# Chart.js doughnut label plugin for centre text incompatible with Chart.js ver 4

Tags: ionic-framework, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js in my Ionic 7.1.1. Angular 16 project.

chart.js": "^4.3.0",
chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0"

The *[chartjs-plugin-doughnutlabel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9tfg7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-doughnut%2Fmy-doughnut.component.ts)* plugin for placing text in the centre of the doughnut chart  appears to be incompatible with current Chart.js with 4x and compatible versions 2.7-3.0.

Is there an alternative plugin or updated plugin?
I have searched around and can only find the vers compatible with Chart.js 2.7-3.0

ADDITION:
Ive added the [chart plugin annotation](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/) :

```
npm install chartjs-plugin-annotation
import 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

This is my chart, but I am getting  type errors on the options :

```
const options = {
      plugins: {
        annotation: {
          annotations: {
            label1: {
              type: 'label',
              xValue: 2.5,
              yValue: 60,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(245,245,245)',
              content: ['This is the label text'],
              font: {
                size: 18
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        //labels: ['BJP','Congress','AAP','CPM','SP'],
        labels: labels,
        //labels: [...labels, totalLabel],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Evenst Per Cateogory',
         // data: [50,29,15,10,7],
         data: data, 
         //data: [...data, this.totalCPDPoints],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
           //'rgba(0,0,0,0)' // Transparent Colour for the total label

          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            '#FFCE56',
            '#FF6384',
            '#36A2EB',
            '#FFCE56',
            '#FF6384'
            //'#000000' // Hover colour for the Total label
          ]
        }]
      },
      options: options
      //options: this.getDonutChartOptions(totalLabel)
```

This is error:

> Type '{ plugins: { annotation: { annotations: { label1: { type:
> string; xValue: number; yValue: number; backgroundColor: string;
> content: string[]; font: { size: number; }; }; }; }; }; }' is not
> assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<"doughnut"> &
> ElementChartOptions<"doughnut"> & PluginChartOptions<"doughnut"> &
> DatasetChartOptions<"doughnut"> & ScaleChartOptions<...> &
> DoughnutControllerChartOptions>'.   The types of
> 'plugins.annotation.annotations' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '{ label1: { type: string; xValue: number; yValue: number; backgroundColor: string; content: string[]; font: { size: number; };
> }; }' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<Record<string,
> AnnotationOptions>> |
> _DeepPartialArray<AnnotationOptions> | undefined'.
> Type '{ label1: { type: string; xValue: number; yValue: number; backgroundColor: string; content: string[]; font: { size: number; };
> }; }' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<Record<string,
> AnnotationOptions>>'.
> Property 'label1' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type '{ type: string; xValue: number; yValue: number; backgroundColor: string; content: string[]; font: { size: number; };
> }' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "label"; } &
> LabelAnnotationOptions> | _DeepPartialObject<{ type: "ellipse"; } &
> EllipseAnnotationOptions> | ... 4 more ... | undefined'.
> Type '{ type: string; xValue: number; yValue: number; backgroundColor: string; content: string[]; font: { size: number; };
> }' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "label"; } &
> LabelAnnotationOptions>'.
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"label"'.
>
> 342       options: options
> ~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/chart.js/dist/types/index.d.ts:3818:3
> 3818   options?: ChartOptions;
> ~~~~~~~
> The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'ChartConfiguration<"doughnut", number[], string> |
> ChartConfigurationCustomTypesPerDataset<"doughnut", number[], string>'

Just not sure I am configuring this plugin correctly, appreciate  feedback.

Update:
Typing *options* to 'any' resolved issue above.

Trying to implement the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d07bmu9/) as below:

```
this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        //labels: ['BJP','Congress','AAP','CPM','SP'],
        labels: labels,
        //labels: [...labels, totalLabel],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Evenst Per Cateogory',
         // data: [50,29,15,10,7],
         data: data, 
         //data: [...data, this.totalCPDPoints],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
           //'rgba(0,0,0,0)' // Transparent Colour for the total label

          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            '#FFCE56',
            '#FF6384',
            '#36A2EB',
            '#FFCE56',
            '#FF6384'
            //'#000000' // Hover colour for the Total label
          ]
        }]
        
      },
      //options: options
      //options: this.getDonutChartOptions(totalLabel)
      
      // Fiddle 
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          center_text:{
            text: "90% green",
            //font: "bold 30px"
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: [{
        id: 'center_text',
        beforeDraw: function ({chartArea: {width, height, top, left}, ctx}, _, options) {
          ctx.save();
          const font = options.font?.trim() || Math.ceil(Math.min(height, width) / 15) + 'px';
          ctx.font = font.match(/\d[^ ]* /) ? font : font + ' sans-serif'
          ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    
          const text = options.text,
            xText = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2) + left,
            yText = height / 2 + top;
    
          ctx.fillText(text, xText, yText);
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }]
    
      
      
});
}
```

I get errors:
*Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'center_text' does not exist in type '_DeepPartialObject<PluginOptionsByType<"doughnut">>'.*

*Property 'font' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['font']*

Comment: For the center text you may use [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/), ([fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/t97u4wLy/)) or even a custom plugin, ([fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6d07bmu9/)). For data labels you may use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/), (see their [doughnut example](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html)).

Comment: Hi, Ive tried importing the plugin - annotation and using in options but am stuck on incompatible types, am I using  this correctly for Ionic / Angular project? See amended question with additional code, thanks

Comment: The plugin is designed for chart types with axes, which doughnut doesn't have, so I had to add the two axes manually. I think the easiest way to solve the error is to use the `as any` typescript solution. The alternative is to add complicated special types for exactly this construct, which I think defies the purpose of type checking. After you make it work without type checking (i.e., with `as any`) you can come back and check if you installed the plugin correctly, including the type definitions (which mornally is the case).

Comment: Hi, I assigned the options type to any, and it complies, however I don't see the label, maybe the axis need to be added as its a doughnut chart? If so, how did u do this , I didn't see instruction in the docs

Comment: Please start from the fiddle I made for you, it contains the axes trick required to position the label in the center.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried to implement the fiddle into my Typescript  code but am getting errors  finding difficult to resolve, have updated the question

Comment: You seem to be mixing the two solutions I proposed in the first message. The [first fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t97u4wLy/) was supposed to be used if you choose to go with the `charjs-plugin-annotation` - you only had to take the two default `scale`s that where used to position the label - they where already under the `options` object that you cast to `any`. If you make your code into a stackblitz or codesandbox, we can fully debug it in one go instead of going back and forth about it on different time zones, which might take too much time for you.